# Single line of file as a Flume event

Tags: flume

I have configured my Flume source to be *spooldir*. I have a lot of CSV files and I want my Flume agent to count / process each line of CSV to be a single event. How will I configure Flume agent to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [`spooldir`](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source) source has a parameter called `deserializer`; the documentation says about it:

> Specify the deserializer used to parse the file into events. Defaults to parsing each line as an event. The class specified must implement EventDeserializer.Builder.

So it should be working.